# Composer.json file has been recreated as .lock file and now is causing artisan errors in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I am trying to make a new controller in Laravel. When I type this command into my CMD window:

```
php artisan make:controller CheckoutController
```

I am getting this error

```
   ErrorException  : file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\composer.j
son): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foun
dation\Application.php:1155
    1151|         if (! is_null($this->namespace)) {
    1152|             return $this->namespace;
    1153|         }
    1154|
  > 1155|         $composer = json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path('composer.
json')), true);
    1156|
    1157|         foreach ((array) data_get($composer, 'autoload.psr-4') as $nam
espace => $path) {
    1158|             foreach ((array) $path as $pathChoice) {
    1159|                 if (realpath(app_path()) == realpath(base_path().'/'.$
pathChoice)) {

  Exception trace:

  1   file_get_contents("C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\composer.json")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Fou
ndation\Application.php:1155

  2   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getNamespace()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Con
sole\GeneratorCommand.php:225
```

I have only started getting this error after installing [Stripe PHP](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) to my composer by doing:

```
composer global require stripe/stripe-php
```

This gave me the output:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\iezonsolutions>composer global require stripe/stripe-php
Changed current directory to C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Using version ^6.28 for stripe/stripe-php
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing stripe/stripe-php (v6.28.0): Loading from cache
Writing lock file
```

Which seems to have delete my `composer.json` file and recreated as a `.lock` file. How can I fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `composer global require` for Stripe. Just `composer require`, typically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Delete the .lock file
2. From you application directory run `composer require stripe/stripe-php` **(NOT GLOBAL)**
3. You might have to re-run composer install or composer update

Comment: You are a star! Thank you so much - I knew I messed up hard when I wrote `global` lol won't be doing that again lmao

Comment: If you are only installing a php package for the particular application you are working on, don't put the global in as this will apply it to your global settings.

Comment: I will be using stripe in all projects but i dint intend to type global, i think i was reading summit about it and it stuck in my brain and i wrote it lol thanks for getting me out that mess mate